# ERROR in R - it cannot support the vector

Tags: r, vector, statistics

I did use the function crop and mean for 434 rasters in Rstudio. Each one is very big, it corresponds almost like 1/4 of Brazil.

Now I want to calculate the standard deviation between these 434 rasters images but this error appears.

I have 66gb of space but it seems that my computer will not process

```
sd_ndvi_caat_crop<-calc(ndvi_caat_crop, sd, na.rm=TRUE, aszero=FALSE)
**Error: cannot allocate vector of size 31.6 Gb**
```

What should I do?

Or if I use the function `cellStats` does it calculate in the same way? Like calculating the sd of each cell of each 434 rasters images?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. I am somehow expecting an error message in your post, yet there seems to be none. Could you add it, please?

Comment: Sorry. sd_ndvi_caat_crop<-calc(ndvi_caat_crop, sd, na.rm=TRUE, aszero=FALSE)#desvio padrao raster#
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 31.6 Gb

Comment: "Very big" is not very precise - can you list the number of rows, columns, and layers for your objects? Is `ndvi_caat_crop` a stack of 434 rasters? I think you might have to divide the stack into chunks and compute the SD raster by parts unless you can get another 64Gb of RAM.

Comment: class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 7220, 5421, 39139620, 434  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 272.4573, 272.4414  (x, y)
extent      : -4580684, -3103693, -2334112, -367085  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)